# Passing parameter - number of users

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm using gatling in linux terminal. When I pass parameter like described in [github](https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Passing-parameters) I get error:

```
 value users is not a member of Integer
```

This is my code:

```
package mypackage

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Headers.Names._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import bootstrap._
import assertions._
import util.Random

class MySimulation extends Simulation {

    val usersCount = Integer.getInteger("users", 1)
    val links = csv("links.csv").random

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseURL("http://mywebsite.com:8080/")
        .acceptCharsetHeader("ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7")
        .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
        .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
        .acceptLanguageHeader("fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3")
        .disableFollowRedirect

    val headers_1 = Map(
        "Keep-Alive" -> "115")
        val headers_3 = Map(
                "Keep-Alive" -> "115",
                "Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

        val scn = scenario("big project benchmark")
        .repeat(50) {
            feed(links)
            .exec(
                    http("request_1")
                            .get("${pageUri}")
                            .headers(headers_1)).pause(1000 millisecond)
        }

    setUp(scn.inject(ramp(usersCount users) over (30 seconds)))
        .protocols(httpProtocol)
        .assertions(global.successfulRequests.percent.is(100), details("request_1").responseTime.max.lessThan(1000))
```

I start this in terminal using:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dusers=300" ./gatling.sh -s mypackage.mySimulation -on testing -sd test1
```

Please, be patient, because I'm totally new to scala and gatling. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the `usersCount users` part of the setUp.

In Scala, this is interpreted as `usersCount.users` which, in our case does not exist since Integer does not have a users method.

I think (but I'm not sure since I cannot test it right now), that you should make usersCount an `Int` like so: `val usersCount: Int = Integer.getInteger("users", 1).toInt`.

Hope this helps!

PS: The reason you should convert `Integer` to `Int` is because of implicit conversions. This is a really powerful feature of Scala.

PPS: The wiki documentation was valid for Gatling 1.X, it will be updated accordingly for Gatling 2.X

Comment: "I think (but I'm not sure since I cannot test it right now), that you should make usersCount an Int like so" If it is necessary, one of `: Int` and `.toInt` should be enough (and it shouldn't be necessary if it's used where `Int` is required, but I also can't test it).

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I would rather let `.toInt` than `: Int` in that case.